# A problem about the eigenvalue of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $n$ is odd number,$A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$,and $BA=0$,if the set of eigenvalue of $A+J_A$ is $S_1$,the set of eigenvalue of $B+J_B$ is $S_2$,which $J_A,J_B$ are Jordan standard form of $A,B$,then I want to  prove $0\in S_1 \cup S_2$.

I want to use $r(A+J_A)+r(B+J_B)\leqslant 2r(A)+2r(B)$,and as $BA=0$,we get $r(A)+r(B)\leqslant n$
,then we get $r(A+J_A)+r(B+J_B)\leqslant 2n$,but only if it less than $2n$ I can prove it.

I find if $n$ is even it will not valid,the example is $A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  0\\
 0&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right) \text{，}J_A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 1&  0\\
 0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$
$B=\left( \begin{matrix}
 1&  0\\
 0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) \text{，}J_B=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  0\\
 0&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $n=2k+1$.

As $BA=O$ we have that $B$ kills every element in the image of $A$, and so
$$
n(B)\geqslant r(A),
$$
where $r$ denotes rank, and $n$ denotes nullity as usual.

By the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have that $r(A)=n-n(A)$, and so
$$
n(A)+n(B)\geqslant n=2k+1.
$$

Hence either $n(A)\geqslant k+1$ or $n(B)\geqslant k+1$.

In the first case we have, since $A$ and $J_A$ are similar, that $n(J_A)\geqslant k+1$ as well.

Then by the $\dim(X+Y)$ Theorem we have
$$
\dim(\ker A\cap\ker J_A)+\dim(\ker A+\ker J_A)=\dim\ker A+\dim\ker J_A\geqslant 2(k+1)= n+1.
$$
As $\dim(\ker A+\ker J_A)\leqslant n$ we must have that
$$
\dim(\ker A\cap\ker J_A)\geqslant 1,
$$
and so there is some non-zero vector killed by both $A$ and $J_A$: this will be a $0$-eigenvector of $A+J_A$.

The argument in the second case is identical.